# Intent Switch - turns to black screen

Tags: android, android-intent, lag

When using the intent switch to another class, after about 5 seconds the screen turns black. And then when i hit the back button it says my app isnt responding. 
What would be cause this to happen? Should i be using threads to fix it?

This is how I switch intents

```
confirm_wager.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    GameBoardActivity.user_player.setGold((player_gold - wager));
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SaloonActivity.this, LiarsDiceActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }
                            });
```

And this is what it is switching to

```
/**
 * Created by noahdavidson on 7/12/16.
 */


public class LiarsDiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private int [] totalDiceHands = new int[6];
private int totalNumOfDice;
private int playersAlive = 5;

private int []player1Dice = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0};
private int player1NumOfDice;
private int []player2Dice = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0};
private int player2NumOfDice;
private int []player3Dice = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0};
private int player3NumOfDice;
private int []player4Dice = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0};
private int player4NumOfDice;
private int []player5Dice = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0};
private int player5NumOfDice;

private int lastCall;
private int lastDice;
private boolean firstTurn = true;


private static final String TAG = LiarsDiceActivity.class.getSimpleName();

//PLAYER HAND DIALOG BOX

int[] matches_img = new int[]{R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five,
        R.drawable.six,R.drawable.seven,R.drawable.eight,R.drawable.nine,R.drawable.ten,
        R.drawable.eleven,R.drawable.twelve,R.drawable.thirteen,R.drawable.fourteen,R.drawable.fifteen,
        R.drawable.sixteen,R.drawable.seventeen,R.drawable.eightteen,R.drawable.nineteen,R.drawable.twenty,
        R.drawable.twentyone,R.drawable.twentytwo,R.drawable.twentythree,R.drawable.twentyfour,R.drawable.twentyfive};

int[] dice_img = new int[]{R.drawable.dice_one,R.drawable.dice_two,R.drawable.dice_three,R.drawable.dice_four,R.drawable.dice_five,
        R.drawable.dice_six};


private int MATCH_BID;
private int DICE_BID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_liars_dice);

    final ImageView match_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    final ImageView dice_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dice);

    final ImageButton match_up = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.match_up);
    final ImageButton match_down = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.match_down);
    final ImageButton dice_up = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dice_up);
    final ImageButton dice_down = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dice_down);

    final Button call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call_button);
    final Button liar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.liar_button);
    final Button show_dice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.roll_button);

    //Set Match and Dice Image
    setMATCH_BID(1);
    setDICE_BID(1);
    setNumMatches(match_view, 0);
    setDiceBid(dice_view, 0);

    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //SET ALL BUTTONS FOR LIARS DICE
            setButtons(match_up,match_down,dice_up,dice_down,call,liar,match_view, dice_view);

            //Set all players w/ 5 Dice
            resetNumPlayersDice();

            //Generate all player hands
            resetHands();

            //set total Dice variable
            setTotalDiceHands();

            //Start Player Turns
            //setShowHandButton(show_dice);
        }
    };


    while(playersAlive > 2){

    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void setShowHandButton(Button show_dice){
    if (show_dice != null) {
        show_dice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //INITIALIZE SHOW HAND DIALOG BOX
                final Dialog show_hand_box = new Dialog(LiarsDiceActivity.this);
                show_hand_box.setTitle("Dice Hand");
                show_hand_box.setContentView(R.layout.show_hand_layout);
                show_hand_box.show();

                //PLAYER HAND VIEW VARIABLES
                ImageView dice1 = (ImageView) show_hand_box.findViewById(R.id.dice1);
                ImageView dice2 = (ImageView) show_hand_box.findViewById(R.id.dice2);
                ImageView dice3 = (ImageView) show_hand_box.findViewById(R.id.dice3);
                ImageView dice4 = (ImageView) show_hand_box.findViewById(R.id.dice4);
                ImageView dice5 = (ImageView) show_hand_box.findViewById(R.id.dice5);
                final ImageView[] player_hand_view = new ImageView[]{dice1,dice2,dice3,dice4,dice5};

                int dCount = 0;
                while (dCount < player1NumOfDice) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        if (player1Dice[i] > 0) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < player1Dice[i]; j++) {
                                if(player_hand_view != null) {
                                    player_hand_view[dCount].setImageResource(dice_img[i]);
                                    dCount++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public void setButtons(ImageButton match_up, ImageButton match_down,ImageButton dice_up,ImageButton dice_down,
                       Button call, Button liar, final ImageView match_view, final ImageView dice_view) {
    ////START BUTTON FUCNTIONALITY////
    if(call != null){
        call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(MATCH_BID < getLastCall () || (MATCH_BID == getLastCall() && DICE_BID <= getLastDice())){
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Bet Higher";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast.makeText(context, text,duration).show();
                }
                setLastCall(MATCH_BID);
                setLastDice(DICE_BID);
                //Log.d(TAG, "call");
            }
        });

    }

    if(liar !=null){
        liar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isFirstTurn() == true){
                }else{
                    //if(tP.getLastCall() >= )
                }
                //Log.d(TAG, "liar");
            }
        });

    }


    if(match_up != null) {
        match_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MATCH_BID += 1;
                if (MATCH_BID == 26) MATCH_BID = 1;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        switch (MATCH_BID){
                            case 1: setNumMatches(match_view,0); break;
                            case 2: setNumMatches(match_view,1); break;
                            case 3: setNumMatches(match_view,2); break;
                            case 4: setNumMatches(match_view,3); break;
                            case 5: setNumMatches(match_view,4); break;
                            case 6: setNumMatches(match_view,5); break;
                            case 7: setNumMatches(match_view,6); break;
                            case 8: setNumMatches(match_view,7); break;
                            case 9: setNumMatches(match_view,8); break;
                            case 10: setNumMatches(match_view,9); break;
                            case 11: setNumMatches(match_view,10); break;
                            case 12: setNumMatches(match_view,11); break;
                            case 13: setNumMatches(match_view,12); break;
                            case 14: setNumMatches(match_view,13); break;
                            case 15: setNumMatches(match_view,14); break;
                            case 16: setNumMatches(match_view,15); break;
                            case 17: setNumMatches(match_view,16); break;
                            case 18: setNumMatches(match_view,17); break;
                            case 19: setNumMatches(match_view,18); break;
                            case 20: setNumMatches(match_view,19); break;
                            case 21: setNumMatches(match_view,20); break;
                            case 22: setNumMatches(match_view,21); break;
                            case 23: setNumMatches(match_view,22); break;
                            case 24: setNumMatches(match_view,23); break;
                            case 25: setNumMatches(match_view,24); break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                //Log.d(TAG, ""+MATCH_BID);
            }
        });
    }


    if(match_down != null){
        match_down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MATCH_BID-=1;
                if (MATCH_BID == 0) MATCH_BID = 25;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        switch (MATCH_BID) {
                            case 1:setNumMatches(match_view, 0);break;
                            case 2:setNumMatches(match_view, 1);break;
                            case 3:setNumMatches(match_view, 2);break;
                            case 4:setNumMatches(match_view, 3);break;
                            case 5:setNumMatches(match_view, 4);break;
                            case 6:setNumMatches(match_view, 5);break;
                            case 7:setNumMatches(match_view, 6);break;
                            case 8:setNumMatches(match_view, 7);break;
                            case 9:setNumMatches(match_view, 8);break;
                            case 10:setNumMatches(match_view, 9);break;
                            case 11:setNumMatches(match_view, 10);break;
                            case 12:setNumMatches(match_view, 11);break;
                            case 13:setNumMatches(match_view, 12);break;
                            case 14:setNumMatches(match_view, 13);break;
                            case 15:setNumMatches(match_view, 14);break;
                            case 16:setNumMatches(match_view, 15);break;
                            case 17:setNumMatches(match_view, 16);break;
                            case 18:setNumMatches(match_view, 17);break;
                            case 19:setNumMatches(match_view, 18);break;
                            case 20:setNumMatches(match_view, 19);break;
                            case 21:setNumMatches(match_view, 20);break;
                            case 22:setNumMatches(match_view, 21);break;
                            case 23:setNumMatches(match_view, 22);break;
                            case 24:setNumMatches(match_view, 23);break;
                            case 25:setNumMatches(match_view, 24);break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                //Log.d(TAG, ""+MATCH_BID);
            }
        });
    }

    if(dice_up != null){
        dice_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DICE_BID+=1;
                if (DICE_BID == 7) DICE_BID = 1;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        switch (DICE_BID) {
                            case 1:setDiceBid(dice_view, 0);break;
                            case 2:setDiceBid(dice_view, 1);break;
                            case 3:setDiceBid(dice_view, 2);break;
                            case 4:setDiceBid(dice_view, 3);break;
                            case 5:setDiceBid(dice_view, 4);break;
                            case 6:setDiceBid(dice_view, 5);break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                //Log.d(TAG, ""+DICE_BID);
            }
        });
    }

    if(dice_down != null){
        dice_down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DICE_BID-=1;
                if (DICE_BID == 0) DICE_BID = 6;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        switch (DICE_BID) {
                            case 1:setDiceBid(dice_view, 0);break;
                            case 2:setDiceBid(dice_view, 1);break;
                            case 3:setDiceBid(dice_view, 2);break;
                            case 4:setDiceBid(dice_view, 3);break;
                            case 5:setDiceBid(dice_view, 4);break;
                            case 6:setDiceBid(dice_view, 5);break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                //Log.d(TAG, ""+DICE_BID);
            }
        });
    }
    /////END BUTTONS////////
}

///// START LIARS DICE GAMING FUCNTIONS///////

public void resetNumPlayersDice(){
    player1NumOfDice = 5;
    player2NumOfDice = 5;
    player3NumOfDice = 5;
    player4NumOfDice = 5;
    player5NumOfDice = 5;

    setTotalNumOfDice(25);
}


public void setMATCH_BID(int MATCH_BID) {
    this.MATCH_BID = MATCH_BID;
}

public int getMATCH_BID() {
    return MATCH_BID;
}

public void setDICE_BID(int DICE_BID) {
    this.DICE_BID = DICE_BID;
}

public int getDICE_BID() {
    return DICE_BID;
}

public void setNumMatches(ImageView view, int num){
    view.setImageResource(matches_img[num]);
}

public void setDiceBid(ImageView view, int num){
    view.setImageResource(dice_img[num]);
}

public int[] setTotalDiceHands (){
    int[] p1 = getPlayer1Dice();
    int[] p2 = getPlayer2Dice();
    int[] p3 = getPlayer3Dice();
    int[] p4 = getPlayer4Dice();
    int[] p5 = getPlayer5Dice();

    //Clear totalDiceHands value
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        totalDiceHands[i]=0;
    }
    //Calculate Total Dice
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        totalDiceHands[i] = p1[i] + p2[i] + p3[i] + p4[i] +p5[i];
    }

    Log.d(TAG,"Total: "+totalDiceHands[0]+","+totalDiceHands[1]+","+totalDiceHands[2]+","+totalDiceHands[3]+","+totalDiceHands[4]+","+totalDiceHands[5]);
    return totalDiceHands;
}

public void resetHands(){
    //5 Players - 5 Dice - reset all hands to 0
    for(int i =0; i < 6;i++){
        player1Dice[i]=0;
        player2Dice[i]=0;
        player3Dice[i]=0;
        player4Dice[i]=0;
        player5Dice[i]=0;
    }

    //Generate all players hands
    if(getPlayer1NumOfDice() > 0){
        genHand(player1Dice,getPlayer1NumOfDice());

        Log.d(TAG,"P1: "+player1Dice[0]+","+player1Dice[1]+","+player1Dice[2]+","+player1Dice[3]+","+player1Dice[4]+","+player1Dice[5]);

    }
    if(getPlayer2NumOfDice() > 0){
        genHand(player2Dice,getPlayer2NumOfDice());

        Log.d(TAG,"P2: "+player2Dice[0]+","+player2Dice[1]+","+player2Dice[2]+","+player2Dice[3]+","+player2Dice[4]+","+player2Dice[5]);
    }
    if(getPlayer3NumOfDice() > 0){
        genHand(player3Dice,getPlayer3NumOfDice());

        Log.d(TAG,"P3: "+player3Dice[0]+","+player3Dice[1]+","+player3Dice[2]+","+player3Dice[3]+","+player3Dice[4]+","+player3Dice[5]);
    }
    if(getPlayer4NumOfDice() > 0){
        genHand(player4Dice,getPlayer4NumOfDice());

        Log.d(TAG,"P4: "+player4Dice[0]+","+player4Dice[1]+","+player4Dice[2]+","+player4Dice[3]+","+player4Dice[4]+","+player4Dice[5]);
    }
    if(getPlayer5NumOfDice() > 0){
        genHand(player5Dice,getPlayer5NumOfDice());

        Log.d(TAG,"P5: "+player5Dice[0]+","+player5Dice[1]+","+player5Dice[2]+","+player5Dice[3]+","+player5Dice[4]+","+player5Dice[5]);
    }
}

public void genHand(int []hand, int totalDice){
    //generate hands based on # of dice left in hand
    for(int i=0; i < totalDice; i++){
        double random = Math.floor(((Math.random() *6) + 1));
        hand[(int)random - 1] += 1;
    }

}

public int[] gettotalDiceHands() {
    return totalDiceHands;
}

public int getTotalNumOfDice() {
    return totalNumOfDice;
}

public void setTotalNumOfDice(int totalNumOfDice) {
    this.totalNumOfDice = totalNumOfDice;
}

public int getLastCall() {
    return lastCall;
}

public void setLastCall(int lastCall) {
    this.lastCall = lastCall;
}

public int getLastDice() {
    return lastDice;
}

public void setLastDice(int lastDice) {
    this.lastDice = lastDice;
}

public boolean isFirstTurn() {
    return firstTurn;
}

public void setFirstTurn(boolean firstTurn) {
    firstTurn = firstTurn;
}
//////END LIARS DICE FUNCTIONS////////


////////PLAYER FUCNTIONS///////
//PLAYER 1 DATA FUNCTIONS
public int[] getPlayer1Dice() {return player1Dice;}

public int getPlayer1NumOfDice() {
    return player1NumOfDice;
}

public void setPlayer1NumOfDice(int player1NumOfDice) {
    this.player1NumOfDice = player1NumOfDice;
}
//END PLAYER 1 FUNCTIONS


//PLAYER 2 DATA FUNCTIONS
public int[] getPlayer2Dice() {return player2Dice;}

public int getPlayer2NumOfDice() {
    return player2NumOfDice;
}

public void setPlayer2NumOfDice(int player2NumOfDice) {
    this.player2NumOfDice = player2NumOfDice;
}
//END PLAYER 2 FUNCTIONS


//PLAYER 3 DATA FUNCTIONS
public int[] getPlayer3Dice() {return player3Dice;}

public int getPlayer3NumOfDice() {
    return player3NumOfDice;
}

public void setPlayer3NumOfDice(int player3NumOfDice) {
    this.player3NumOfDice = player3NumOfDice;
}
//END PLAYER 3 FUNCTIONS

//PLAYER 4 DATA FUNCTIONS
public int[] getPlayer4Dice() {return player4Dice;}

public int getPlayer4NumOfDice() {
    return player4NumOfDice;
}

public void setPlayer4NumOfDice(int player4NumOfDice) {
    this.player4NumOfDice = player4NumOfDice;
}
//END PLAYER 4 FUNCTIONS

//PLAYER 5 DATA FUNCTIONS
public int[] getPlayer5Dice() {return player5Dice;}

public int getPlayer5NumOfDice() {
    return player5NumOfDice;
}

public void setPlayer5NumOfDice(int player5NumOfDice) {
    this.player5NumOfDice = player5NumOfDice;
}
//END PLAYER 5 FUCNTIONS
///////END PLAYER FUNCTIONS/////
```

}

Comment: Please share the code for the second activity as well as the code you use to start it.

Answer (score 0):

Im dumb there was an infinite while loop.......

Answer (score -1):

Actually, if you start Activity from A_Activity to B_Activity, you can't cost much time in A-onPause(), A-onStop() and B-onCreated(). cause i don't know the full code, so i just give this tip.